# QT File writing with arrays

Tags: c++, qt, file, csv, qt5

Im trying to read from csv file into another file. There aren't any errors, I just don't understand why it is not writing into the file. Any help is appreciated. Im very new to QT.

```
QString arr[581][6];
while (!file.atEnd()) {
    QByteArray line = file.readLine();

    for (int i=0; i<581; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++){

            arr[i][j]=line;

        }
    }
}

QString Hfilename="c:\Data.txt";
QFile fileH( Hfilename );
if ( fileH.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) )
{
    QTextStream stream( &fileH );

    for (int i=0; i<581; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++){

            stream<<arr[i][j]<<endl;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Double up the backslash in the string literal: `"c:\\Data.txt"`. Also, a non-administrative user might not have sufficient permissions to create a file in the root of the drive; the `open` call might be failing. Also, are you sure there's at least one non-empty string in the array? Check that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [QDataStream unable to serialize data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045488/qdatastream-unable-to-serialize-data)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The default Windows ACL for drive root directories grants "Everyone" Full Control (important subdirectories like Program Files and Windows are obviously more restricted), so anyone should be able to create files there. Any given system can be reconfigured differently, but this is the default.

Comment: @AndrewMedico When I run Notepad and try to save a file into `C:\ `, a message pops up saying `C:\a.txt You don’t have permission to save in this location. Contact the administrator to obtain permission.` I'm 99.9% sure permissions on my system are at their defaults.

Comment: My mistake. All authenticated users can create new folders in the root directory, but not new files.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I tried what you suggested and it didn't created the file

Comment: @AndrewMedico I'm not sure what your saying.

Comment: Right-click the EXE file and choose "Run as administrator". Or else, modify your program so that it doesn't attempt to write under `C:\ ` but someplace under your user profile (normally `C:\Users\<your username>` )

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you provided, please find a working example for the write step (you specified that the read step is alrady working):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString arr[3];
    arr[0] = "xxxxxx";
    arr[1] = "yyyy";
    arr[2] = "zzzz";

    QString Hfilename="/home/jhondoe/toto.txt";
    QFile fileH( Hfilename );
    if ( fileH.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) )
    {
        QTextStream stream( &fileH );
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
            stream << arr[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

What changed:

- I (my user account) has sufficient rights to write into the output file
- If you work on Windows, as @igor-tandetnik said, you have to use double backslashes as separator. You can also use QDir::separator() as native separator for your file path.

Comment: I assumed because I wasn't getting errors, I was reading from the file correctly, but my file is empty. Do you know how to read from this file. Is their something missing from the code I provided above?

Comment: Why don't you simply use qDebug or std::cout to print the content of your 'line' variable in the loops? Doing this, you will be able to confirm or infirm that your code for reading file is valid.